# get request from form in HTML by using query parameters

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, ejs

I am new to this whole concept, so I am sorry if I am asking a basic question.

My HTML page has following form element,

```
<form method="POST" action="/:user">
<label>user :<label>
<input type="text" id="user" name="user">
<label>password :</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password">
<button> Submit <button>
</form>
```

My part of nodejs code from server side when calling this post method is:

```
app.post('/:user',(req,res)=>{
console.log(req.params.user);
})
```

All excluding this HTML element are working fine.
In the above HTML code, let's say if I give user input some name as " john", my idea is that it should call the router mentioned in the below nodejs code on the server-side.
But the way it is working is, it is calling the '/:user' rather than calling the '/'.Please help me how to change the action in the form element in HTML above, so as to have the desired output. By the way, I'm using ejs framework for HTML.

Comment: By using <form action="/:user"> you are telling your form element where it should send the request to. So currently it is trying to send it to yourdomain/:user. If you leave it out, it will send the request simply to the document's address. Is that what you are asking?